# Is it worth taking Diao Chan or Shangxiang in Empire Defense 2?

Tags: empire-defense-2

Has someone tried the new female characters Diao Chan and/or Shangxiang in Empire Defense 2? How do they fight? They are very expensive but their stats are very low...

Answer (score 1):

I have played **[Империя TD Tower Defense](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mangolee.empire.towerdefense.ru)** which seems to be the Russian version of Empire defense II. But the game language is still English. I have gone to the 26th battles in story without any use of the Diao Chan and Shangxiang . I used LIU BEI,GUAN YU and ZHAO YUN to defeat enemies. The most important part of the defense battles are the select of soldiers and strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Shangxiang is very good her special attack of moving the higher health enemies back to he beginning of the path handy in the area I'm like top 35000 in the area. Plus her leadership stats are very good

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading your solders and weapons may benefit more.

Shangxiang: A very powerful general in the arena. The stats are a little low, but the aforementioned special attack is very powerful. by not killing the enemies like most other special attacks do AND return them（better than Zhuge Liang's stunning) to delay their death, you can mine more gold in the spared time which may bumps your final score and crystal gained if you leave them unused at the end of match. Combined with stunning and freezing troops and you get yourself a good farming platoon (of course you need to be strong enough to survive, probably with the help of good cloths and weapons). It is kind of boring to wait for the miners, however.

Diao Chan: Having the best range in the game does not help much if the general's attack is weak (can be improved with weapon upgrades later in the game). Her special attack is relatively weak but covers the full map. Somehow she has better leadership than most other male generals, which means better attacks from troops, good for large maps.